# FullCalendar - Delete selected events

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, fullcalendar

I am using JQuery fullcalendar with asp.net MVC....

Target: Delete from database using "select(callback)"

Issue: I need the event's ids from each day selected to drop it from DB.

```
select: function (start, end, jsEvent, ---> events(need this) <---) {

    foreach(event**)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "../calendar/Delete",
            data: {
                id: id
            }
        }).done(function (partialView) {
            $alert.sucess('Done');
        });
    }
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("unselect");
}
```

** I know foreach doesn't work but ignore this please

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Not yet, can you help me?

Comment: You want to remove event from database while clicking on event, right?

Comment: No, when i click on a day i need to get the event id of all events on that day.

Comment: What if you have multiple events on same day? want remove all event on same day?

Comment: Exactly, i need the id from all events of clicked day

Comment: What are your events keys? like id, title etc. do you have any unique id for event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
dayClick: function( date, jsEvent, view) {
    var daysEvent = [];
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function (event){
        if(date.format('YYYY-MM-DD') == event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD')) {
            daysEvent.push(event.id);
        }

    });
    if(daysEvent.length) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "../calendar/Delete",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                id: daysEvent.join(',')
            }
        }).done(function (partialView) {
            $.each(daysEvent, function(key,id) {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', id);
            });
            $alert.sucess('Done');
        });;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Vanderlei Did you try this?

Comment: This doesn't work for me - fullCalendar isn't an attribute of ``$('#calendar')`` 

At least not working in v5